# Global two dimension array in subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I'm making a CFD program which uses arrays. In the final part of the code, shown below, I have the subroutine `INIT` which will put the variable temperature at the value 0. The temperature is a two dimensional array declared in the main program.

The problem is that when I call the subroutine `INIT` it doesn't know that I already declared the array `T(NN,NN)`. In other words, the array is not detected in the subroutine.

How can I fix this? How can I set `T(NN,NN)` as like a global variable?

```
! VARIABLES

PARAMETER (NN=100)
DIMENSION X(NN),Y(NN),DXPW(NN),DXEP(NN),DYNP(NN),DYPS(NN),SEW(NN),SNS(NN),T(NN,NN)

...

WRITE(*,*)
SNS(1)=0.0
SNS(NJ)=0.0
DO J=2,NJM1
SNS(J)=0.5*(DYNP(J)+DYPS(J))
WRITE(*,*)SNS(J)
END DO

CALL INIT(NI,NJ)

END

SUBROUTINE INIT(NI,NJ)
DO I=1,NI
DO J=1,NJ
    !T(I,J)=0.0
END DO
END DO
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: ok, did it! It's not the whole code though.

Comment: you know you can just do `t=0` no need forthat subroutine at all

Comment: I know, but I will have more complex subroutines, and if this one doesn't work, other won't either.

Comment: use a contains construct http://stackoverflow.com/q/35808053/1004168

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32386146) asks about means of passing data between a program and other procedures.  Essentially, the "common blocks" it talks about is what you mean by "global variable".

Comment: Use modules for global variables, or (in many cases much better!) pass the array as an argument of the subroutine.

Comment: The question linked to by francescalus has far more relevant information for this question than the question about CONTAINS.  What's best will depend on specifics, but the implied recommendation with the current "duplicate" to use host association is rather questionable - in some cases using host association for this sort of thing would be quite poor style.

Comment: I reopened, as suggested by @IanH.